# ASP.NET project templates missing after installing update 3 for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After I installed the latest Visual Studio 2013 update, I cannot see any templates in the new project popup. Everything is disabled.

How can I get them back?

[image: no template is available :(]

Comment: Try a "Repair" installation, from Control Panel Programs.

Comment: Jessica, Uninstall VS, delete the "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" directory, and then reinstall Visual Studio 2013 Web Update 3. For more details follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20/25276352#25276352)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20/25276352#25276352).

All I had to do is to delete

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll
```

and

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll

in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies