# No MVC 5 Template in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I´m using Visual Studio Professional 2013. When I wan't to create a MVC 5 Project (with .NET Framework 4.5.1 or 4.5) I go to "New Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web" select "ASP.NET Web Application" (the only Option) and click OK. In the next Window however there are no Options for me to choose a Template for the Application I want to create, it's just a blank Window.[Link to the Picture](http://imgur.com/KeRnhHC)

I tried to reapir Visual Studio but it didn´t help.

Comment: if the mvc templates are missing, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096746/how-to-add-mvc5-to-visual-studio-2013). If _all_ templates are missing try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1250064.aspx?My+visual+studio+templates+dialog+box+is+empty+No+templates+are+displayed+Please+help+)

Comment: I tried everything described in that article but it still isn't working

Comment: Due to whatever Reason I don't have a Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt, however I have a Visual Studio 2012 Command Prompt even though I never installed the 2012 Version

Comment: seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476588/where-is-developer-command-prompt-for-vs2013)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

You could potentially try the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255683/asp-net-project-templates-missing-after-installing-update-3-for-visual-studio-20), delete:

- *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll*
- *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll*

Which is located here: 
 - *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies*

---

In Visual Studio 2013, you have a single choice:

[image]

You'll choose your one template, then on the next screen:

[image]

The second screen is where you'll define the type of your Asp.Net project.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, because the OP does not see the list of templates.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Didn't see the image and the small amount of text, gave him a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have found your templates, but you want good templates you can check http://asptemplatestack.com/Templates/GetAll . It's still in beta but   you can download a lot of MVC templates. It provides very good backend structure.