# Cannot create MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

When I click **File > New > Project...**, select **Templates > Visual C# > Web** and select the **ASP.NET Web Application** template, I am faced with the **New ASP.NET Project** dialog box, which prompts me to select a template. I only have the options for **Empty**, **Web Forms** or **Azure Mobile Service**.

[image: Template Selection]

I cannot select an MVC 5 template.

I have found solutions such as this:
[Can't create new MVC5 project or any other ASP .NET projects in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270008/cant-create-new-mvc5-project-or-any-other-asp-net-projects-in-visual-studio-20) however that doesn't solve my problem as I don't have the specified assemblies that it suggests need deleting, and also the problem described isn't identical.

I had the same problem in Update 3, but assumed that if I installed Update 4 the problem would sort itself out, but it hasn't.

I have searched quite a lot but can't find any posts with the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add MVC5 to Visual Studio 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096746/how-to-add-mvc5-to-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Also have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237299/no-mvc-5-template-in-visual-studio-2013?lq=1 which should clarify things with the images in the answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question, I get the same behaviour whether I select .NET version 4.5, 4.5.1 or 4.5.2.

Comment: This SO post may interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823499/visual-studio-2013-no-visual-basic-visual-c-sharp-web-templates-installed

Comment: Thanks @PaulZahra - repairing Visual Studio worked.